# Does tumbling window trigger in Azure Synapse automatically know what data has been generated or modified since the last run?

Tags: azure-data-factory

When using tumbling window triggers in Azure, does the tumbling window only pick up data generated or modified since the last run, or does it perform a full load of data every time and we have to defined the incremental load logic in some other way ?

If we need to define custom logic, how would we do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-tumbling-window-trigger?tabs=data-factory,azure-powershell),

> No, toumbling window triggers cannot pick the last modified data. Everytime, it performs as per the pipeline flow. It cannot identify the latest data or old data. It's job is to trigger the pipeline on given windows and whatever the logic the pipeline was built, it will execute it. You cannot use this trigger for the incremental load.

Also, you can see there will be no option to specify anything related to type Data loading in the trigger creation process.

[image]

You need to define the incremental load logic in your pipeline and trigger that as per your requirement. You can use [CDC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-change-data-capture) (Change Data Capture) for this.

But Currenlty, CDC supports only [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-change-data-capture#auto-incremental-extraction-in-mapping-data-flow) connectors. So, go through the documentation and check whether both your source and target databases in that list or not as per your use case.

If not, then you need to use water mark column concept. Check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-overview) to know more about this approach.